# Cell double click event in data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two `DataGridView` events. I have a problem, when I double click on a cell, both the events i.e., `cell click` and `cell double click` events are being invoked. please provide me with answer why this occured and whats solution.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know how to use but I think it can be solved using `hook` and `unhook`. or else `Timer`.

Comment: Please refer this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252735/double-click-to-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Hope this hepls:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to that just by setting properties in of the DataGridView. So you can use Timer to count if there was any double click, if not just do whatever you do in yous single click event handler, check the code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            t.Interval = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime - 1;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            DataGridViewCellEventArgs dgvcea = (DataGridViewCellEventArgs)t.Tag;
            MessageBox.Show("Single");
            //do whatever you do in single click
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Tag = e;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Double");
            //do whatever you do in double click
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i want to stop cell click event to be invoked when cell double click invocked

Comment: @user1835772 OK, but I don't think there is a way to do that. Why this would be a problem? This works exactly as you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: @user1835772 Could you provide link, I would like to see that, looks interesting

Comment: @user1835772 Hope that I helped you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Its with Windows problem. as far i know they haven't added anything special to handle it.

You can handle this -

- a) just make single click something you'd want to happen before a double click, like select.
- b) if that's not an option, then on the click event, start a timer. On the timer tick, do the single click action. If the double-click event occurs first, kill the timer, and do the double click action.

The amount of time you set the time for should be equal to the system's Double-Click time (which the user can specify in the control panel). It's available from `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`.

- Checkout this MSDN link-  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172533.aspx)
- Also this discussion [Stackoverflow question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218555/how-can-i-differentiate-between-single-and-double-clicks-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RowHeaderMouseClick event of grid

```
    private void dgv_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {

    }
```