# VB DataGridView CellMouseClick event Prevents CellMouseDoubleClick

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mouseevent

I'm using Visual Basic to write a WinForm Application. In my DataGridView I have the Selection Mode property set to CellSelect. I am trying to set my DataGrid up so that on a single click, a few textboxes are populated with some data, and on a double click, it will open up a new form and display all kinds of other info.

I have tried both the CellClick + CellDoubleClick events as well as the CellMouseClick + CellMouseDoubleClick however, everytime I double click, the single click event fires first and prevents the doubleclick event from ever firing.

Maybe this is just a lack of understanding on my part and I need to do something different, I thought about just adding a button column and firing the buttonclick event but that will require a lot of re-coding since I hard-coded existing data columns properties such as Column(1...15).visible = false and a lot more. Anyone have any thoughts on how to get both events to fire?

Double Click event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
    CallLookup.ShowDialog()
    Dim PatientID As String = SelectGrid.Rows(SelectGrid.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("PatientID").Value.ToString
    PatientID = CallLookup.patientID2
End Sub
```

Single Click

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick1(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
  Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dispatchtxt2.Text = (reader("PickupDispatchedTime").ToString)
            Enroute2Txt.Text = (reader("PickupEnRouteTime").ToString)
            OnScene2Txt.Text = (reader("PickupOnSceneTime").ToString)
            Transport2Txt.Text = (reader("PickupTransportTime").ToString)
            Arrival2Txt.Text = (reader("PickupArrivalTime").ToString)
            clear2txt.Text = (reader("PickupClearTime").ToString)
   End While
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        DataGridView1.InvalidateRow(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I left a few lines out that were just a data connection

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453992/cell-double-click-event-in-data-grid-view ?

Comment: I have not. I tried to get the timer solution to work however It still isn't firing the double click.

Comment: Never Mind, It wasn't firing because I had a debug breakpoint set on the single click event so that was affecting the timer I guess. Thanks for the helpful link!